# How to pass string and dictionary in NUnit test cases?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, nunit

I want to make test for my method and I can pass 2 string variables, but I don't know how to pass the `Dictionary<,>`.

It looks like this:

```
[Test]
[TestCase("agr1", "askdwskdls", Dictionary<TypeMeasurement,double>)]
public void SendDataToAgregator_GoodVariables_ReturnsOn(string agrID,string devID, Dictionary<TypeMeasurement, double> measurement)
{

}
```

`TypeMeasurement` is `enum` and I know that this is not how you pass dictionary, but I don't know how, so I place it there so that you know what I want to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of `TestCaseAttribute`, if you have complex data to use as a test case, you should look  at `TestCaseSourceAttribute`

> TestCaseSourceAttribute is used on a parameterized test method to identify the property, method or field that will provide the required arguments

You can use one of the following contructors:

```
TestCaseSourceAttribute(Type sourceType, string sourceName);
TestCaseSourceAttribute(string sourceName);
```

This is explantion from the [documentation](http://nunit.org/docs/2.6/testCaseSource.html):

> If sourceType is specified, it represents the class that provides the
>   test cases. It must have a default constructor.
>
> If sourceType is not specified, the class containing the test method
>   is used. NUnit will construct it using either the default constructor
>   or - if arguments are provided - the appropriate constructor for those
>   arguments.

So you can use it like below:

```
[Test]
[TestCaseSource(nameof(MySourceMethod))]
public void SendDataToAgregator_GoodVariables_ReturnsOn(string agrID,string devID, Dictionary<TypeMeasurement, double> measurement)
{

}

static IEnumerable<object[]> MySourceMethod()
{
    var measurement = new Dictionary<TypeMeasurement, double>();
    // Do what you want with your dictionary

    // The order of element in the object my be the same expected by your test method
    return new[] { new object[] { "agr1", "askdwskdls", measurement }, };
};
```

Comment: I tried this, but now compiler is saying that I don't have enough parameters, he created 3 test cases from this. @CodeNotFound

Comment: @Serlok It should be `return new[] { new object[] { "agr1", "askdwskdls", measurement }, };`. If you like, you can also change the type of the property to `static object[][] MySourceProperty` for clarity. Or `IEnumerable<object[]>` (in which case you can use `yield return` if you like).

Comment: I edited my answer @Serlok you should return an array of array :)

Comment: To prevent typos and the false belief that the propert is not used, you can change `[TestCaseSource("MySourceProperty")]` into `[TestCaseSource(nameof(MySourceProperty))]`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen u sir just helped me after 2h of trying, ty very much!

Comment: @CodeNotFound ty for providing answer, just a little thing, `yield` can't be used here because of compiler error : The body of 'AMICharacteristics_Test.MySourceProperty.get' cannot be an iterator block because 'object[]' is not an iterator interface type AMI_Device_Test

Comment: I noticed it. Edited 5mn ago.

Comment: how can you pass paramter into MySourceMethod?