# unit test cases for converters in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, converters

I have defined a converter in my project. I want to begin with writing unit test case for that converter.

Code for converter is:

```
   public class BirdEyeViewColumnWidthConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public int BirdEyeModeWidth { get; set; }
        public int DefaultWidth { get; set; }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                if ((bool) value)
                {
                    return BirdEyeModeWidth;
                }
            }
            return DefaultWidth;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

How do I start with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I start with this?

1. Add a Unit Test Project (.NET Framework) to your solution. (New Project->Installed->Visual C#->Test in Visual Studio).
2. Add a reference to the project where your `BirdEyeViewColumnWidthConverter` is defined from the newly create unit test project. Project->Add Reference->Projects->Solution.
3. Rename and write the unit test in `TestMethod1()` of the generated `UnitTest1` class.

In this method you create an instance of your converter class, call its `Convert` method and assert that the returned value is what you expect it to be, e.g.

```
[TestClass]
public class BirdEyeViewColumnWidthConverterTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void BirdEyeViewColumnWidthConverterTest()
    {
        const int BirdEyeModeWidth = 20;
        const int DefaultWidth = 10;

        BirdEyeViewColumnWidthConverter converter = new BirdEyeViewColumnWidthConverter()
        {
            BirdEyeModeWidth = BirdEyeModeWidth,
            DefaultWidth = DefaultWidth,
        };

        int convertedValue = (int)converter.Convert(true, typeof(int), null, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Assert.AreEqual(BirdEyeModeWidth, convertedValue);

        convertedValue = (int)converter.Convert(false, typeof(int), null, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Assert.AreEqual(DefaultWidth, convertedValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday I tried something similar, but instead of object I had dictionary, so maybe this will help u [TestCaseSourceAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50437491/how-to-pass-string-and-dictionary-in-nunit-test-cases)

Also, when u implement arguments, check if returning type is same as one u are expecting - e.g. `Assert.IsInstanceOf(typeof(DateTime), obj.CreationTime);`

Comment: So, here I need to compare the return type of which 2 objects?

Comment: My bad, I misread given example.  As I can see from ur given code, u will pass `value` as NOT null object and u want to get `BirdEyeModeWidth` property, so u need to check is ur methods returning u given property. U first need to instantiate object that is of type class where those properties are stored and then maybe something like this `Assert.IsInstanceOf(typeof(int),obj.BirdEyeModeWidth)`